# Savon request fail

Tags: ruby, savon

I'm using savon 0.9.7 and ruby 1.8.7, I make this request:

```
client = Savon::Client.new do
  wsdl.document = "http://localhost:3000/wsdl/service.asmx?WSDL"
end

response = client.request "Body3DGeneration" do
  soap.body = {
    :path => 'adsa',
    :measures => 'assaasd',
    :landmarks => 'adsd'
  }
  http.headers["SOAPAction"] = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/services/1"
end
```

Savon send this POST:

```
SOAPAction: http://xx.xx.xx.xx/services/1, 
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8, 
Content-Length: 526

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:wsdl="http://xx.xx.xx.xx/services" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ins0="http://xx.xx.xx.xx/services" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Body>
    <ins0:Body3DGeneration>
      <ins0:path>adsa</ins0:path>
      <ins0:measures>assaasd</ins0:measures>
      <ins0:landmarks>adsd</ins0:landmarks>
    </ins0:Body3DGeneration>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

But the server requires something like that:

```
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/services/1"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Body3DGeneration xmlns="http://xx.xx.xx.xx/services">
      <path>string</path>
      <landmarks>string</landmarks>
      <measures>string</measures>
    </Body3DGeneration>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm getting the next error:

```
SOAP response (status 500):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
      <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.</faultstring>
      <detail />
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Savon::SOAP::Fault: (soap:Server) Server was unable to process request. ---> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
```

Can you help me? I think that I don't do good savon request but I don't find anything on the documentation.

Comment: Sorry guys, this error is a server response, the parameters are wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check server using raw query example

```
  response = client.request do |soap| 
      soap.xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>....'
      http.headers["SOAPAction"] = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/services/1"
   end
```